# modification to manifest.json of installed extension is not effective

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I installed an extension and edited directly manifest.json in .config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/`<extid>`/`<version>`/manifest.json (Linux) but this does not reflect in the behavior of the extension even after restarting the browser.

I am making changes to the `externally_connectable` config in manifest.json.

Does that mean that Chrome stores the actual manifest.json somewhere else?

Comment: I would expect that to work.  What change are you making to the manifest?  Could you post before and after of the relevant portion?

Comment: I am making changes to the externally_connectable config in manifest.json.

Comment: Did you visit `chrome://extensions/`, scroll to the extension and press "Reload"? (Develop)

Comment: @RobW "Reload" option is enabled for only locally added extensions from hard-drive under "developer mode" of Chrome. I am talking about modifing manifest.json of extension added from chrome-web-store. Restarting the browser also does not help.

Comment: @KrishnaSrinivas Edit `Default/Preferences` and put the permission at the relevant extension ID. That will probably work.

Comment: @RobW Did not work :-( my changes to `Default/Preferences` got reverted when I restarted Chrome.

Comment: @KrishnaSrinivas Did you edit that file *after* closing Chrome?

Comment: @RobW good find! editing the file after closing Chrome preserves the changes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Currently chrome puts a copy of the (possibly [localized](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n)) manifest into the Preferences file, and reads from there on startup.

As some comments noted, this will be in .config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences. Note that this is *not* intended to be a stable interface to make changes for extensions or anything else governed by data in that file; you should expect the location/format/validation of the file to change any time without notice.